# Hive on spark doesn't work in hue

Tags: hive, oozie, hiveql, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to trigger hive on spark using hue interface . The job works perfectly when run from commandline but when i try to run from hue it throws exceptions. In hue, I tried mainly two things:

1) when I give all the properties in .hql file using set commands

```
set spark.home=/usr/lib/spark;
set hive.execution.engine=spark; 
set spark.eventLog.enabled=true;
add jar /usr/lib/spark/assembly/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-cdh5.5.1-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.5.1.jar;
set spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://10.11.50.81:8020/tmp/;
set spark.executor.memory=2899102923;
```

I get an error

```
ERROR : Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Unsupported execution engine: Spark.  Please set hive.execution.engine=mr)'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unsupported execution engine: Spark.  Please set hive.execution.engine=mr
```

2) when I give properties in hue properties, it just works with mr engine but not spark execution engine.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any good reason to use that `oozie` tag?!?

Comment: i am creating a oozie workflow and that's the reason for the oozie tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using a shell action in oozie.
This shell action invokes a pyspark action bearing my sql file.

Even though the job shows as MR in jobtracker, spark history server recognizes as a spark action and the output is achieved.

shell file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
spark-submit --master local testabc.py
```

python file:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext();
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
result = sqlContext.sql("insert into table testing_oozie.table2 select * from testing_oozie.table1 ");
result.show()
```